# How would i do first and second parts?

Tags: arrays, c, logic

Consider we have to choose a Leader from n people. For this purpose, we create an
array of size n. We assign every candidate a number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,….,n) and store it in array in
ascending order. We apply dancing chair (People struggle to get the chair!!! After stopping the
music, in each iteration one chair and one man is eliminated. The Final remaining one is the
winner) method. Suppose we start from index 0 then we have to skip 3 indexes and we will reach
at index 3. Set its value to zero and start again from index 4 and skip 3 indexes and we will reach at index 7. Repeat the same step and so on.

(1) When we reach at last index we will proceed to index 0 again (for example the last index is 19, we start the count from index 18 and skip 3 indexes then we will reach at 1 and set it to zero).

(2) If the reached element value is already 0 than set the next element to zero. Do the same process till only one element remaining?

We implement it by using array and function. Write a function SelectLeader () which takes array
as input and return the Leader.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int SelectLeader() {
    int n, i;
    int leader = 0;
    printf("Enter total number of people to choose a Leader from: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int array[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i = (i + 3) % n) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            array[(i + 1) % n] = 0;
        } else
            array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] != 0) {
            leader = i;
        }
    }
    return leader;
}

int main() {
    int L;
    L = SelectLeader();
    printf("Leader is the candidate with the index number %d\n", L);
}
```

Comment: I would format the code first.

Comment: "_How would i do first and second parts?_" - of what? Please specify the problem in detail.

Comment: Are you asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70331150/im-not-getting-the-desired-output-what-am-i-doing-wrong)? You haven't corrected the `i<=n` error.

Comment: Are you posting your school assignments?

Comment: Note that with `i = (i + 3) % n` the `i` will *always* be `< n`, so there is an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, it's a school assignment. I've already submitted without this question because it was given as a bonus. I'm sorry, I just really can't understand this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pesudo code

Suppose n= 10 , for easy understanding
I am creating a boolean `flag array` to check whether number is selected or not.

```
jump = 3
i = 0
for (int cnt=0;cnt<10;) {

  if(flag[i%10] === false) {
      flag[i%10]=true;
      cnt+=1;
      i+=jump;
  }

  else {
     i+=1;
  }

}
```

The index element remaining with `flag false` is ans.

However this approach is both space and time expensive.

Comment: Oh, let me try this one

Comment: Nah man, I tried. I can't make sense of the errors I'm producing with this. And I don't know how to return the 'flag false' answer. Is there an approach easier than this?

Comment: you can return the `fanswer` by running a loop upto n and break when flag[i]==false, that value of `i` will be the answer . This is brute force approach.